# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'gpu_fraction'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am now using colab for my reproduction of saliency detection!
I'm a student, so please understand that my knowledge is not enough,,,
I found the code using `tensorflow`, so I am trying to use that code to reproduce the project.
However, the author said the code was written on tensorflow 1.00 but I don't know the version of `tensorflow` if I just `import tensorflow as tf` from colab.
I am getting the error

> 'tuple' object has no attribute 'gpu_fraction'

and

> module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GPUOptions'

Here is my source code please see what's my problem

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np

import os

from scipy import misc

import argparse

import sys


g_mean = np.array(([126.88,120.24,112.19])).reshape([1,1,3])

output_folder = "./test_output"

def rgba2rgb(img):
    return img[:,:,:3]*np.expand_dims(img[:,:,3],2)

def main(args):

    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.mkdir(output_folder) 

    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = args.gpu_fraction)
    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options = gpu_options)) as sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./meta_graph/my-model.meta')
        saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./salience_model'))
        image_batch = tf.get_collection('image_batch')[0]
        pred_mattes = tf.get_collection('mask')[0]

        if args.rgb_folder:
            rgb_pths = os.listdir(args.rgb_folder)
            for rgb_pth in rgb_pths:
                rgb = misc.imread(os.path.join(args.rgb_folder,rgb_pth))
                if rgb.shape[2]==4:
                    rgb = rgba2rgb(rgb)
                origin_shape = rgb.shape
                rgb = np.expand_dims(misc.imresize(rgb.astype(np.uint8),[320,320,3],interp="nearest").astype(np.float32)-g_mean,0)

                feed_dict = {image_batch:rgb}
                pred_alpha = sess.run(pred_mattes,feed_dict = feed_dict)
                final_alpha = misc.imresize(np.squeeze(pred_alpha),origin_shape)
                misc.imsave(os.path.join(output_folder,rgb_pth),final_alpha)

        else:
            rgb = misc.imread(args.rgb)
            if rgb.shape[2]==4:
                rgb = rgba2rgb(rgb)
            origin_shape = rgb.shape[:2]
            rgb = np.expand_dims(misc.imresize(rgb.astype(np.uint8),[320,320,3],interp="nearest").astype(np.float32)-g_mean,0)

            feed_dict = {image_batch:rgb}
            pred_alpha = sess.run(pred_mattes,feed_dict = feed_dict)
            final_alpha = misc.imresize(np.squeeze(pred_alpha),origin_shape)
            misc.imsave(os.path.join(output_folder,'alpha.png'),final_alpha)

def parse_arguments(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('--rgb', type=str,
        help='input rgb',default = None)
    parser.add_argument('--rgb_folder', type=str,
        help='input rgb',default = None)
    parser.add_argument('--gpu_fraction', type=float,
        help='how much gpu is needed, usually 4G is enough',default = 1.0)
    return parser.parse_args(argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(parse_arguments(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try just getting rid of the explicit GPU configuration, i.e. turn your

```py
    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=args.gpu_fraction)
    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)) as sess:
```

into

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:
```

Comment: Really sorry for keep asking, but then I got 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rgb_folder' error from
 if args.rgb_folder:
   rgb_pths = os.listdir(args.rgb_folder)

Comment: Since you're using Colab, how are you calling `main()`? You need to call it with a suitable `args` object – an easy way to get one here is `args = parse_arguments(('--rgb_folder', 'my_folder_name_here'))`

Comment: I have the feeling your Colab environment has TensorFlow 2.0, which has a different API. You can try `tensorflow.compat.v1.Session()` instead, but there will likely be other changes too. You should probably look into installing the last TF 1.x version, i.e. TensorFlow 1.14, in your environment.

Comment: Oh I solved those questions by now!!!! Thank U So Much!!
Really sorry, but I don't get what it means for rgb_folder error,,,, :(
You mean I just add args = parse_arguments(('--rgb_folder','./test')) before that line?

Comment: Depends on how you're calling `main()`, again. It expects an `args` object – the sort `parse_arguments()` returns, not a tuple.

Comment: Thank You SO much,,,,,, Maybe this will be last question :( I got error called No registered 'BroadcastTo' OpKernel for GPU devices compatible with node {{node unpool_4/mul}}
  (OpKernel was found, but attributes didn't match) Requested Attributes: T=DT_INT64, Tidx=DT_INT32

What should I do,,,,,?

Comment: I'd _guess_ your GPU doesn't support the data format required by the model... You can maybe force things to run on CPU with `tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU')` (via https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31135)